# How to specify different .dockerignore file for Visual Studio Code's Dev Container?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, dockerignore

Is it possible to specify a different `.dockerignore` file for Dev Container in VSCode? I checked the documentation and couldn't find anything relevant.

The use case I'm looking for is ignoring `.git` directory in regular `.dockerignore` and not ignoring it in VSCode so that git extensions work while in Dev Container.

Comment: any hint about the issue?

Comment: @AliMassoud pretty sure it's currently impossible, I added an issue: https://github.com/devcontainers/spec/issues/401